# Would it be beneficial to incorporate the el-nino tag and prempt a la-nina tag under an ENSO tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Should we combine these tags? Or is it better they remain separate?

Comment: the enso tag now exists and both el-nino and (pre-emptively) la-nina are synonyms.

Comment: Thanks Casey.  (wibble)

Answer (score 9):

I think we should make [enso](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enso) the master tag and make both [el-nino](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/el-nino) and [la-nina](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/la-nina) synonyms to it.  To do this we'll need to re-tag one of the el-nino questions to enso to create the tag and then we can synonym the other tags to it.

I can take care of this if the community agrees.  I'll leave this here for a bit to see how the votes turn out, but I don't see any reason why it shouldn't get support.